# Trying to create /boot for Fedora 23 and getting error "local variable 'e' referenced before assignment"

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora

I am running on pre-installed Windows 8 and am trying to install fedora 23 on 133Gb de-allocated space on my hard drive via LiveUSB.
In installation, when I try to manually add /boot under LVM, it comes up with a "Failed to add new device   local variable 'e' referenced before assignment".I verified the iso, wiped my unallocated space, and reinstalled the iso on the liveUSB. Also, Some bug was reported and fixed on what seemed like the same or very similar issue. ([here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1249304)) However, I am still getting this error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Ascendant you had the same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

turns out the reason I was having this issue was because I had already used up my four primary partitions and needed to free one up in order to install fedora.

Comment: Hmmmm. That shouldn't cause an obscure error. As noted in the bug you linked, that was supposed to be fixed in beta. If you can still reproduce it, could you please file a new bug? Thank you! (from Fedora!)